# Error after implementing StartApp Sdk

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, startapp

I have just implemented StartApp SDK to serve add in my application but it is giving error like below. The error showing in crash report. Please help to remove the error and avoid crash

Please see the crash report below

```
Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface methodjava.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
com.startapp.android.publish.j.c.a ()
com.startapp.android.publish.j.c.a ()
com.startapp.android.publish.g.c.a ()
com.startapp.android.publish.g.d.d ()
com.startapp.android.publish.g.d$1.run ()
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

Here is my Java file

```
package sujaynambiar.textilecalculation;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.startapp.android.publish.StartAppAd;
import com.startapp.android.publish.StartAppSDK;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ComberTotalDraftDrafting extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText inputBattTension, inputFeedAmount, inputNoil, inputBattWeight, inputSliverHank;
    TextView answer;
    Spinner spinner;
    Button calculate, buttonFormula;
    final Context context = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        StartAppSDK.init(this, "210963358", true);
        StartAppAd.disableSplash();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comber_total_draft_drafting);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        inputBattTension = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputBattTensionComberTotalDraft);
        inputBattTension.addTextChangedListener(new NumberTextWatcherForThousand(inputBattTension));
        inputBattWeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputBattweightComberTotalDraft);
        inputBattWeight.addTextChangedListener(new NumberTextWatcherForThousand(inputBattWeight));
        inputNoil = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputNoilBComberTotalDraft);
        inputNoil.addTextChangedListener(new NumberTextWatcherForThousand(inputNoil));
        inputFeedAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputFeedAmountComberTotalDraft);
        inputFeedAmount.addTextChangedListener(new NumberTextWatcherForThousand(inputFeedAmount));
        inputSliverHank = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSliverHankComberTotalDrfat);
        inputSliverHank.addTextChangedListener(new NumberTextWatcherForThousand(inputSliverHank));
        answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerComberTotalDraft);
        calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculateComberTotalDraft);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerSelectCountUnit);
        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        list1.add("Ne");
        list1.add("kTex");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.custom_simple_spinner, list1);
        dataAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner_dropdown);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);
        calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int index = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                double value1 = 0;
                double value2 = 0;
                double value3 = 0;
                double value4 = 0;
                double value5 = 0;
                if (inputBattTension.getText().toString().isEmpty() ||
                        inputFeedAmount.getText().toString().isEmpty() ||
                        inputNoil.getText().toString().isEmpty() || inputBattWeight.getText().toString().isEmpty()
                        || inputSliverHank.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.toastmessage3),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else {
                    value1 = Double.parseDouble(inputBattTension.getText().toString().replaceAll(",", ""));
                    value2 = Double.parseDouble(inputFeedAmount.getText().toString().replaceAll(",", ""));
                    value3 = Double.parseDouble(inputNoil.getText().toString().replaceAll(",", ""));
                    value4 = Double.parseDouble(inputBattWeight.getText().toString().replaceAll(",", ""));
                    value5 = Double.parseDouble(inputSliverHank.getText().toString().replaceAll(",", ""));
                }
                if (index == 0) {
                    double answer1 = 0;
                    answer1 = (0.417 * value2 * value4 * ((100 - value1) / 100) * ((100 - value3) / 100) * value5);
                    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
                    formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
                    formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
                    answer.setText(formatter.format(answer1) + " ");
                }
                if (index == 1) {
                    double answer2 = 0;
                    answer2 = (((0.245 / value5) * value2 * value4 * ((100 - value1) / 100) * ((100 - value3) / 100)));
                    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
                    formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
                    formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
                    answer.setText(formatter.format(answer2) + " ");
                }
            }
        });
        buttonFormula = (Button) findViewById(R.id.formulaComberTotalDraft);
        buttonFormula.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_formula);
                TextView title = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.title);
                title.setText(R.string.ComberTotalDraftCalculation);
                ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.test_image);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.combertotaldraftne);
                ImageView image1 = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.test_image1);
                image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.combertotaldraftktex);
                TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
                text.setText(R.string.Formula_ComberTotalDraftCalculation);
                Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
                dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        StartAppAd.onBackPressed(this);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/layoutbackgroundcolor">
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/startAppBanner"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/layoutbackgroundcolor"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="sujaynambiar.paid.ComberTotalDraftDrafting"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_comber_total_draft_drafting">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/dot"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/separator_textview"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/FirstViewMarginTop"
            android:background="@drawable/separator"
            android:layerType="software" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/RL1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dot"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/gap_for_all"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_left"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_right"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_right"
                android:layout_weight="1.25"
                android:text="@string/showtext52"
                android:textColor="@color/textviewtextcolor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/TextViewSize" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/inputBattTensionComberTotalDraft"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_left"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_right"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_right"
                android:layout_weight="1.75"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/dot1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/RL1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/separator_textview"
            android:background="@drawable/separator"
            android:layerType="software" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/RL2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dot1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/gap_for_all"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_left"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_right"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_right"
                android:layout_weight="1.25"
                android:text="@string/showtext51"
                android:textColor="@color/textviewtextcolor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/TextViewSize" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/inputBattweightComberTotalDraft"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_left"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_right"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_right"
                android:layout_weight="1.75"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/dot2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/RL2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/separator_textview"
            android:background="@drawable/separator"
            android:layerType="software" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/RL3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dot2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/gap_for_all"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView16"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_left"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_right"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_right"
                android:layout_weight="1.25"
                android:text="@string/showtext50"
                android:textColor="@color/textviewtextcolor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/TextViewSize" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/inputNoilBComberTotalDraft"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_left"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_right"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_right"
                android:layout_weight="1.75"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/dot5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/RL3"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/separator_button"
            android:background="@drawable/separator"
            android:layerType="software" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/RL4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dot5"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/gap_for_all"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView17"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_left"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_right"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_right"
                android:layout_weight="1.25"
                android:text="@string/showtext49"
                android:textColor="@color/textviewtextcolor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/TextViewSize" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/inputFeedAmountComberTotalDraft"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_left"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_right"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_right"
                android:layout_weight="1.75"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/dot6"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/RL4"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/separator_textview"
            android:background="@drawable/separator"
            android:layerType="software" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView18"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dot6"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/TextView_Spinner"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_left"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_right"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_right"
            android:text="@string/showtext43"
            android:textColor="@color/textviewtextcolor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/TextViewSize" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView18"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/TextView_Spinner"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_left"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_right"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_right"
            android:text="@string/showtext30a"
            android:textColor="@color/textviewtextcolor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/TextViewSize" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/RL5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/gap_for_all"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerSelectCountUnit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_left"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_right"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_right"
                android:layout_weight="1.25"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/inputSliverHankComberTotalDrfat"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_left"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_right"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_right"
                android:layout_weight="1.75"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/dot7"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/RL5"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/separator_button"
            android:background="@drawable/separator"
            android:layerType="software" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/calculateComberTotalDraft"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dot7"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/button_separator"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_left"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_right"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_right"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:text="@string/calculate"
            android:textColor="@color/buttontextcolor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/ButtonText" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/dot8"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/calculateComberTotalDraft"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/separator_answer"
            android:background="@drawable/separator"
            android:layerType="software" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/answerComberTotalDraft"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/answerViewSize"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dot8"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/answerview_separator"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_left"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_right"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_right"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/answer"
            android:textColor="@color/textviewtextcolor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/AnswerView" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/dot10"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/answerComberTotalDraft"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/separator_button"
            android:background="@drawable/separator"
            android:layerType="software" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/formulaComberTotalDraft"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dot10"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/button_separator"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_left"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_right"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_right"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:text="@string/formula"
            android:textColor="@color/buttontextcolor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/ButtonText" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/dot9"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/formulaComberTotalDraft"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/separator_textview"
            android:background="@drawable/separator"
            android:layerType="software" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
    <com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner
        android:id="@+id/startAppBanner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is there a way to not obfuscate that library?

Comment: This the message I got from StartApp.......
StartApp In-Ad is already obfuscated! Therefore, if you did not obfuscate your application using ProGuard™, then you can skip this step. If you have obfuscated your application using ProGuard, then use the following in the ProGuard configuration file:

-keep class com.startapp.** {
      *;
}

-keepattributes Exceptions, InnerClasses, Signature, Deprecated, SourceFile,
LineNumberTable, *Annotation*, EnclosingMethod
-dontwarn android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
-dontwarn com.startapp.**

Comment: Okay, so while you figure that out, try putting `setContentView` before `StartAppSDK.init`

Comment: But in StartApp documentation the below method is described to implement the method........  In your main activity, go to the OnCreate method and before calling setContentView() call the static function:

StartAppSDK.init(this, "Your App ID", true);
Replace "Your App ID" with your own value provided in the developers’ portal.